# Similar matrices properties

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a question which I can not solve.

Assuming $A,B \in \mathbb{M_{n}(\mathbb{R})}$, $A$ similar to $B$, is it possible that $\det(A) = \det(B^{2})+1$?

We know that there exists $P$ (invertible) such that $P^{-1}AP=B$ and therefore $B^{2} = P^{-1}A^{2}P$.  This means that
$$
\det(B^{2})=\det(P^{-1}A^{2}P)=\det(P^{-1})\det(A^{2})\det(P)=\det(A)^2.
$$

So the question is actually is it possible to find $A \in \mathbb{M_{n}(\mathbb{R})}$ such that 
$$\det(A) = \det(A)\det(A)+1.$$

And I do not know how to continue from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: If $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\det(A) \in \mathbb{R}$ but the equation $x^{2} - x + 1 = 0, \, x \in \mathbb{R}$ has no real solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that what you have is a quadratic equation: if $t:=\det(A)$, then
$$
t^2-t+1=0\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad t=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4}}{2}=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$
So, if such a matrix $A$ existed, it would need to have one of these as its determinant.  Can a real matrix have non-real determinant?

Comment: Writing $i \sqrt{3}$ instead of $\sqrt{3}i$ might improve readability.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\det A$

$x=x^2+1$

You can solve that, can't you?

Answer (score 3):

You have an equation
$$
x = x^2 + 1.
$$
That is
$$
x^2 - x + 1 = 0.
$$
The solutions to this equation are
$$
x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4}}{2} = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}.
$$
That is, you would need $\det(A)$ to be one of these (complex) numbers.